# Can the kloudless iOS SDK services page be customized?

Tags: ios, responsive-design, kloudless

When calling `[[KAuth sharedAuth] authFromController:self]` the modal page that comes up (I'm assuming this is a web view loading a URL) with all the different services is not formatted for mobile. Is there a way to format this so that the text is readable on iOS?

[image: Example of Klodless account link screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Kloudless. We'll get on making that responsive. That should greatly improve the experience on mobile and is probably the easiest way to solve this problem. The other alternative would have been to build a native view for the service selection screen.

I'll be sure to update you when this change is released.

Comment: Thanks Vinod, I took your advice and started implementing my own native version of your page. The only snag I hit is that now that have all my buttons laid out I can't call the KAuth object to authenticate the selected service. I'd have to create my own webview and send it to the correct URL and capture the result. Basically recreate a lot of the functionality you guys already did. Is there a better way to make this native screen work? This is probably it's own separate question, but thanks.

Comment: It would probably be best to modify the iOS SDK to allow for individual services to be authenticated. I believe that all that would have to be done is to allow for an optional service name to be specified at https://github.com/Kloudless/kloudless-ios/blob/master/KloudlessSDK/KloudlessSDK/KAuth.m#L91 so that the URL would end in `services/gdrive` for example, rather than just `services/` We'll get on testing that change soon, but if you'd like to implement this immediately, that change should help you.

Comment: Man you are fast with your comments sir. I just tried this very thing before reading your comment and it works. I basically rewrote the code on the `authFromController` method and changed the URL like you said to the service I want. Writing this feature into the SDK would be cool too, but I least there's a way forward.